# I want to fetch the live stock price data through google search

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to fetch the real time stock price through google search using web scraping but its giving me an error

```
resp = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=apple+share+price&oq=apple+share&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.11811j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8")
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text,'lxml')
tab = soup.find('div',attrs = {'class':'gsrt'}).find('span').text
```

> 'NoneType'object has no attribute find

[image]

Comment: Sounds like `soup` is coming back as `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
soup.select_one('td[colspan="3"] b').text
```

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
res = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=apple+share+price&oq=apple+share&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.11811j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8', headers = headers)
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
quote = soup.select_one('td[colspan="3"] b').text
print(quote)
```

Comment: That class, you are using, is not present in the response html. It is always worth remembering that requests won't produce the same html as the webpage using browser in most instances. Often JS running on the page affects the DOM structure/content

Answer (score 1):

Try this maybe...

```
resp = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=apple+share+price&oq=apple+share&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.11811j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8")
soup = bs(resp.text,'lxml')
tab = soup.find('div', class_='g').findAll('span')
print(tab[3].text.strip())
```

or, if you only want the price..

```
resp = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=apple+share+price&oq=apple+share&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.11811j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8")
soup = bs(resp.text,'lxml')
tab = soup.find('div', class_='g').findAll('span')
price = tab[3].text.strip()
print(price[:7])`
```

Comment: it worked but Why did you put the class_=g? Its gsrt in the source code

Comment: What is- price[:7] ?

Comment: @TarangSomani I'm not in front of the computer but to answer both your questions. 1 - gsrt might be in the source code but I found the data you wanted in div class='g'. 2 - price is a string that included other data too. So I wanted only the price and since it is a string[:7] grabs only those characters starting with the very first and only up to the 8th index, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`user-agent` is not specified in your request. It could be the reason why you were getting an empty result. This way Google treats your request as a [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) aka automated script, instead of a "real user" visit.

It's fairly easy to do:

1. Click on [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension (*once installed*).
2. Click on the stock price and receive a `CSS` selector provided by SelectorGadget.
3. Use this selector to get the data.

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Search-Scrape-Answer-Box-Stocks-Data-python#bs4_result.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=nasdaq stock price', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

current_stock_price = soup.select_one('.wT3VGc').text
print(current_stock_price)

>>> 177,33
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing using [Google Direct Answer Box API](https://serpapi.com/direct-answer-box-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches.

The biggest difference in this example that you don't have to figure out why the heck something doesn't work, although it should. Everything is already done for the end-user (*in this case all selections and figuring out how to scrape this data*) with a `json` output.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "nasdaq stock price",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

current_stock_price = results['answer_box']['price']
print(current_stock_price)

>>> 177.42
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.